# how to know if list is being set right now? spring multithreading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I have a List named people that gets update every 72 hours, I also have a Controller that returns this list:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getPeople() {
    List<String> people = peopleService.getPeople();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(people);
}
```

I'm afraid that there will be times where I return a partial list because at the same time I'm doing an update to the list in the service, something like this:

```
people = getPeople();
```

I also get a call from the controller and I should return this list that sometimes get updated so it's kind of related to multithreading.

I was thinking about a boolean variable named isProcessing that wll be like that:

```
isProcessing = true;
people = getPeople();
isProcessing = false;
```

What do you think, maybe there is other way to solve the problem? Thanks.

Edit: 
I use the spring scheduler annotation to update the list every 72 hours, I don't update the list in another scenarios.
I'm not using a database, I have a call to an API, I get Json, and I start a calculation and in the end I collect all the names I need to a list and put this list inside people so the people list get update every 72 hours.

As @Cargeh said, I'm afraid of this situation:
**"you start a read, myList is pointing to List#1. You keep reading it. In the mean time, update occurs and sets myList to List#2 (newList here), while you keep reading List#1.**

Comment: You are headed down the wrong path if you have to ask the question, "How do I know if ... _right now?_"  The problem is, even if thread B can ask  what thread A is doing, thread A can _change_ what it is doing in between thread B asking, and thread B acting on that information.

Comment: You are right, that's my problem

Comment: @T.S. Regarding your **bold** sentence - you will simply read "old" list to the end - end of story. If you want to overcome that issue you just simply synchronize access to the list, or in case of DB -serialize accces. End of story. If client code had no problems in reading 1 version of list of 72 hours, then it should not have problems with +1 extra read of "old" list.

Comment: @T.S. IMHO you are seeing problem where there is none - just lock access to list when you are about to update and you are done - consumers will gracefully wait for update to finish.

Comment: @Antoniossss, so my idea to make a boolean variable isProcessing and set it to true when I start the update and false when I finish the update is what you say, right? When isProcessing is true, consumers will sleep for 2 seconds and try again to see if the update has finished.

Comment: Close, but dont use booleans(double check locking and stuff can happen there) but rather dedicated utility from java.concurrent package - eg `Sepamhore` You ca also  be straight and simple and for synchronized blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is almost like @Oreste Viron. The thing with his first answer is that you need to synchronize the end of the cache with the scheduler and there is still a gap where the user gets to wait (end of cache-> scheduler -> time for loading list -> ready to use). So my idea is :

```
@GetMapping
@Cachable("CACHE_NAME")
public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getPeople() {
   List<String> people = peopleService.getPeople();
   return ResponseEntity.ok(people);
}
```

In PeopleService :

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 */3 * *")
@CachePut(value = { CACHE_NAME })
public List<String> getPeople() {  
   ...
}
```

just don't forget `@EnableScheduling` and `@EnableCaching` on config file.

Comment: I edited my post, can you tell me if your solution is still right for my problem?

Comment: I think so. I just can't tell if there is an unnegligent time for updating cache. If there is none, all good. The idea here is that people that are calling your API always get the cached value. The scheduled fonction will call the targeted API without interfering your mapping and when the list is done fetching, the scheduled fonction will replace the old cached data with the new ones. Ni vu ni connu!

Answer (score 0):

You can just swap list snapshots;

```
private volatile List<Person> myList; // here you keep the snapshot

    public List<Person>getPPL(){
        return myList;
    }

    void modifyList(){
       List<Person> newList=/// do whatever you want 
       this.myList=newList;

    }
```

If data is fetched from the DB, you just have to set proper isolation level to block uncommited changes (or even serialize access)

Comment: This is not sufficient, it will not cover the dirty reads issues.

Comment: You begin to write persons, the update occurs, you continue your read.
You end with an inconsistent answere.

Comment: Nope not a chance here

Comment: Dirty reads : http://codingsight.com/understanding-dirty-read-problem-sql-server/

Comment: @OresteViron no dirty read can occur here, look closer. Otherwise provide a scenario where this can happen.

Comment: I already explain : you start a read, the update occurs when the read is not finished yet.

Comment: @OresteViron you explained nothing - there is no such posiblility here. You just described what dirty reads are and what IN FACT OP is asking how to prevent.

Comment: @OresteViron you start a read, `myList` is pointing to `List#1`. You keep reading it. In the mean time, update occurs and sets `myList` to `List#2` (`newList` here), while you keep reading `List#1`. These are two different lists. What's the problem here?

Comment: @Cargeh : your scenario still assumes you are not in a transactional database.

Comment: @Antoniossss : I'm ready to hear what prevent dirty read in your scenario.

Comment: @OresteViron because this question is not database related. Stop making imaginary conditions which suit your scenarios.

Comment: I edited the post, I get the data from Json, then I do some calculation on that Json and then get the names I need which is a list of people.

Comment: @OresteViron Cargeh is 110% right and that is the whole point of solution. DB has nothing to do with it as this shall be done by transaction isolation. You accuse Carageh of making asumptions while its you that making an assumption that DB is somewhere here. 
All in all - solution works

Comment: @Cargeh +1 for making imaginary conditions ;)

Comment: @Antoniossss : you also assumed that he fetch data from DB. My comments are meant to discuss about the solutions in that context. But I see you have no more arguments.

Comment: @OresteViron Hehe please show me where I assumed that he uses DB I dare you. There is no point in arguing with you as you keep living in imaginary world and you are blocked to what ppl say to you. You got right (in your mind) and that is all that count. So yeah, I have no more arguments than those rock solid Iv already put ahead, but without effect.

Comment: In your answer. You have twelve or what ?

Comment: You do know it is a conditional statement? No? Oh, sorry for you

Answer (score -1):

I think about 2 solutions.

1) Keep your list Cached in your service, only update the list 1 time each 72 hours (with scheduler).

2) If the changes of your person list are transactional, you can tell your database to not read lines when transaction is not done.
See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Comment: I edited the post, option number 1 is correct, I update the list once every 72 hours with the scheduler annotation. so should I do what's written in GabLeg answer?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid answer. You could do this without using @Cache, but it's a matter of preference.